# PHP - SOAP Array stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, soap

So I'm trying to parse an array of results I get back from a SOAP query. However PHP seems to be giving me grief (more likely I'm giving myself grief). I want to echo out all the user objects that are retrieved from the query.

Results from query:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["row"]=> array(4) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "0c69d6a4-a4a7-0a68-ac47-e3b9279fb25e" ["userid"]=> string(7) "Kitchen" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "60c858b6-71fd-4c6b-0bc7-18c56a07127e" ["userid"]=> string(7) "Control" } 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "b59301fc-a197-6d50-b217-7d8967332601" ["userid"]=> string(5) "House" } 
[3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "dcf8b18d-cf95-4ffd-85d2-a6f9b45f5fc9" ["userid"]=> string(47) "Token_User_4806a7a1-f23d-4647-b46c-f62ad66452a0" } } }
```

Code for result:

```
$response = $client->executeSQLQuery(array("sql"=>"select pkid,userid from enduser"));
    //        var_dump($response);
    foreach ($response as $row){
        var_dump($row);
}
```

Now I can get one deeper into the array by altering the code as follows:

```
    foreach ($response as $row){
        var_dump($row->row);
}
```

However this doesn't work to access just the userid element:

```
    foreach ($response as $row){
        var_dump($row->row->userid);
}
```

PHP instead returns:
`PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object`

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Just a quick update:
Source query:

```
$response = $client->executeSQLQuery(array("sql"=>"select pkid,userid from enduser"));
    //        var_dump($response);
    foreach ($response as $row){
      var_dump($row);
//echo("USER: ".$row->userid)."<br>";
}
```

`var_dump` of `$row` returns:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["row"]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "0c69d6a4-a4a7-0a68-ac47-e3b9279fb25e" ["userid"]=> string(7) "Kitchen" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "60c858b6-71fd-4c6b-0bc7-18c56a07127e" ["userid"]=> string(7) "Control" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "b59301fc-a197-6d50-b217-7d8967332601" ["userid"]=> string(5) "House" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "dcf8b18d-cf95-4ffd-85d2-a6f9b45f5fc9" ["userid"]=> string(47) "Token_User_4806a7a1-f23d-4647-b46c-f62ad66452a0" } } }
```

`var_dump` of `$response` returns:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["return"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["row"]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "0c69d6a4-a4a7-0a68-ac47-e3b9279fb25e" ["userid"]=> string(7) "Kitchen" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "60c858b6-71fd-4c6b-0bc7-18c56a07127e" ["userid"]=> string(7) "Control" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "b59301fc-a197-6d50-b217-7d8967332601" ["userid"]=> string(5) "House" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["pkid"]=> string(36) "dcf8b18d-cf95-4ffd-85d2-a6f9b45f5fc9" ["userid"]=> string(47) "Token_User_4806a7a1-f23d-4647-b46c-f62ad66452a0" } } } }
```

Comment: Your outermost `var_dump($row)` is an object containing an array property called `row`. Each of its elements is an object, with a `pkid` and `userid` property.  So `$row->row[0]->userid` for example, to get the first. Or `foreach ($row->row as $user)`

Comment: When I attempt your suggestion `foreach ($response->row as $row)` I end up getting back PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). You are correct though if I do `$row->row[0]->userid` it does in fact return the first item in the array. However I want it to keep looping for each item in the array and return them all.

Comment: The object posted above at the top is `var_dump($response)`? Please edit to post the output of `var_dump($response)` copied from the browser page source, so all the indentation and line breaks are left intact.

Comment: It's just a matter of which variable name the object dumped at the top is. If that's `$row` (sounds like maybe it is) then you need `foreach ($row->row as $item) { echo $item->userid; }`

Comment: So I added the additional `var_dump`. I think I see where I'm getting confused. I need to loop foreach of the objects which in my case is 0, 1,2,3 etc. to return the property of userid. However each time I use the `->` I end up just adding another array object named `row`. For example If I do `foreach ($response as $row->row->row)` I will end up with two more `row` array objects with only one item which is the next array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumb, this is the same problem I had in another post. I basically need to access the `return->row` objects then I'm able to access the `pkid` or `userid` properties in the array.

Final code looks like:

```
$response = $client->executeSQLQuery(array("sql"=>"select pkid,userid from enduser"));
//        var_dump($response);
foreach ($response->return->row as $row){
//        var_dump($row->userid);
echo("USER: ".$row->userid)."<br>";
}
```